# NUnit 3.0 console doesn't work with "include" parameter

Tags: nunit-3.0

Before NUnit 3.0 I used the next parameter to include category of tests to execute: `/include:"name"`

Now in NUnit 3.0 the writing seems to be different - according to this: https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Command-Line-Options

I have to use something like: `-include=name` but it seems to me that correct option would be `--include=name` as I write other parameters like `--workers` the same way and they work.

The problems is that when I use `--include` parameter I get error: `"Invalid argument: --include=Selenium"`(Jenkins console shows me this error).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dug dipper and somewhere found that for now there is no `--include` parameter!

**What we should use instead is**: `--where "cat==name"`

cat = category. If we wanna to take priority into consideration we'll do something like this: `--where "cat==name && Priority==High"`

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Shame the NUnit documentation makes no mention of the where clause at all!

Comment: If the documentation doesn't contain the where clause, then you are looking at the older documentation, which we maintain for legacy purposes. Start at nunit.org and follow Documentation menu item, then select current docs.

Comment: Documentation for the nunit test selection language: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language

Comment: also, use "!=" when you want to EXCLUDE